# Working with Old Babylonian cuneiform in TeXstudio

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm fairly new to using LaTeX and have been using the default font up until now. I need to implement a font called Santakku in order to typeset cuneiform characters, but have had trouble finding clear information on the topic. From a few google searches, I've figured out I should probably be using XeTeX instead of pdfTeX, but I'm still at a loss as to how to implement the actual font. My preamble goes:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\setmainfont{Santakku}
```

After that, I haven't had any luck implementing the signs. For example, the sign KA is unicode character U12157, and I thought that I may have to do something like this for each sign:

```
\char{12157} or something along these lines...
```

If I do have to type signs in some such way, might I be able to configure LaTeX so that I can type something like this instead:

```
\KA or \AN\KA and so on...
```

Thank you!

EDIT: In case you're reading this as you try to find a good way to typeset cuneiform, I should point out that Santakku is OB cursive only. If you're aiming for lapidary signs, you should use the SantakkuM variant.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\symbol{"12157}`, not `\char`. You can do `\newcommand{\KA}{\symbol{"12157}`.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly. Would I be able to make a file full of all my commands then link that in when I need them in a document?

Comment: Note that `xlxtra` used to be recommended, but it's not so any longer; just load `fontspec`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an example; you shouldn't make Santakku as the main font, because it lacks support for several used characters and it seems much like a poor clone of Times for the non cuneiform part. If your editor has font support, you can even type in the characters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\cuneiform}[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Santakku}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcuneiform}{\cuneiform}

\newcommand{\AN}{\symbol{"1202D}}
\newcommand{\KA}{\symbol{"12157}}

\begin{document}

This is cuneiform \textcuneiform{\AN\KA}.

This is cuneiform \textcuneiform{}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You might define a table of equivalents in a file, called `cuneiform.tex` containing

```
\newcommand{\AN}{\symbol{"1202D}}
\newcommand{\KA}{\symbol{"12157}}
```

and the other necessary macros. Put it into a place where TeX will look (this depends on your system, see [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)) and do

```
\input{cuneiform}
```

when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

[image: cuneiform]

A full sign-list is possible, but will require some handcrafting.

The existential question becomes: how to name all of them.

`\newcommand` checks if the command name already exists, and ignores digits (although the `\csname ABC123\endcsname` construct gets around that last part, but it is a lot to type).

As a demo, the 922 glyphs of the Cuneiform unicode block, using the first part of the glyph name as a base name, and adding b,c,d,... to distinguish multiples. Some have more than 26 - haven't worked out how to deal with them, and keep the typing simple.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{red!3}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{english}


\setmainfont{Akkadian}%Noto Sans Cuneiform}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Noto Serif}

\newcommand\A{\symbol{"12000}}
\newcommand\Ab{\symbol{"12001}}
\newcommand\Ac{\symbol{"12002}}
\newcommand\Ad{\symbol{"12003}}
\newcommand\Ae{\symbol{"12004}}
\newcommand\Af{\symbol{"12005}}
\newcommand\Ag{\symbol{"12006}}
\newcommand\Ah{\symbol{"12007}}
\newcommand\Ai{\symbol{"12008}}
%\newcommand\A2{\symbol{"12009}}
\newcommand\AB{\symbol{"1200A}}
\newcommand\ABb{\symbol{"1200B}}
\newcommand\ABc{\symbol{"1200C}}
\newcommand\ABd{\symbol{"1200D}}
\newcommand\ABe{\symbol{"1200E}}
\newcommand\ABf{\symbol{"1200F}}
\newcommand\ABg{\symbol{"12010}}
\newcommand\ABh{\symbol{"12011}}
\newcommand\ABi{\symbol{"12012}}
\newcommand\ABj{\symbol{"12013}}
\newcommand\ABk{\symbol{"12014}}
\newcommand\ABl{\symbol{"12015}}
%\newcommand\AB2{\symbol{"12016}}
%\newcommand\AB2b{\symbol{"12017}}
%\newcommand\AB2c{\symbol{"12018}}
%\newcommand\AB2d{\symbol{"12019}}
%\newcommand\AB2e{\symbol{"1201A}}
%\newcommand\AB2f{\symbol{"1201B}}
\newcommand\AD{\symbol{"1201C}}
\newcommand\AK{\symbol{"1201D}}
\newcommand\AKb{\symbol{"1201E}}
\newcommand\AKc{\symbol{"1201F}}
\newcommand\AL{\symbol{"12020}}
\newcommand\ALb{\symbol{"12021}}
\newcommand\ALc{\symbol{"12022}}
\newcommand\ALd{\symbol{"12023}}
\newcommand\ALe{\symbol{"12024}}
\newcommand\ALf{\symbol{"12025}}
\newcommand\ALg{\symbol{"12026}}
\newcommand\ALh{\symbol{"12027}}
\newcommand\ALi{\symbol{"12028}}
\newcommand\ALAN{\symbol{"12029}}
\newcommand\ALEPH{\symbol{"1202A}}
\newcommand\AMAR{\symbol{"1202B}}
\newcommand\AMARb{\symbol{"1202C}}
\newcommand\AN{\symbol{"1202D}}
\newcommand\ANb{\symbol{"1202E}}
\newcommand\ANc{\symbol{"1202F}}
\newcommand\ANd{\symbol{"12030}}
\newcommand\ANe{\symbol{"12031}}
\newcommand\ANSHE{\symbol{"12032}}
\newcommand\APIN{\symbol{"12033}}
\newcommand\ARAD{\symbol{"12034}}
\newcommand\ARADb{\symbol{"12035}}
\newcommand\ARKAB{\symbol{"12036}}
%\newcommand\ASAL2{\symbol{"12037}}
\newcommand\ASH{\symbol{"12038}}
\newcommand\ASHb{\symbol{"12039}}
\newcommand\ASHc{\symbol{"1203A}}
\newcommand\ASHd{\symbol{"1203B}}
\newcommand\ASHe{\symbol{"1203C}}
\newcommand\ASHf{\symbol{"1203D}}
%\newcommand\ASH2{\symbol{"1203E}}
\newcommand\ASHGAB{\symbol{"1203F}}
\newcommand\BA{\symbol{"12040}}
\newcommand\BAD{\symbol{"12041}}
%\newcommand\BAG3{\symbol{"12042}}
%\newcommand\BAHAR2{\symbol{"12043}}
\newcommand\BAL{\symbol{"12044}}
\newcommand\BALb{\symbol{"12045}}
\newcommand\BALAG{\symbol{"12046}}
\newcommand\BAR{\symbol{"12047}}
%\newcommand\BARA2{\symbol{"12048}}
\newcommand\BI{\symbol{"12049}}
\newcommand\BIb{\symbol{"1204A}}
\newcommand\BIc{\symbol{"1204B}}
\newcommand\BId{\symbol{"1204C}}
\newcommand\BU{\symbol{"1204D}}
\newcommand\BUb{\symbol{"1204E}}
\newcommand\BUc{\symbol{"1204F}}
\newcommand\BUd{\symbol{"12050}}
\newcommand\BULUG{\symbol{"12051}}
\newcommand\BULUGb{\symbol{"12052}}
\newcommand\BUR{\symbol{"12053}}
%\newcommand\BUR2{\symbol{"12054}}
\newcommand\DA{\symbol{"12055}}
\newcommand\DAG{\symbol{"12056}}
\newcommand\DAGb{\symbol{"12057}}
\newcommand\DAGc{\symbol{"12058}}
\newcommand\DAGd{\symbol{"12059}}
\newcommand\DAGe{\symbol{"1205A}}
\newcommand\DAGf{\symbol{"1205B}}
\newcommand\DAGg{\symbol{"1205C}}
\newcommand\DAGh{\symbol{"1205D}}
\newcommand\DAGi{\symbol{"1205E}}
\newcommand\DAGj{\symbol{"1205F}}
\newcommand\DAGk{\symbol{"12060}}
\newcommand\DAGl{\symbol{"12061}}
\newcommand\DAGm{\symbol{"12062}}
\newcommand\DAGn{\symbol{"12063}}
\newcommand\DAGo{\symbol{"12064}}
\newcommand\DAGp{\symbol{"12065}}
\newcommand\DAGq{\symbol{"12066}}
\newcommand\DAGr{\symbol{"12067}}
\newcommand\DAGs{\symbol{"12068}}
\newcommand\DAGt{\symbol{"12069}}
\newcommand\DAGu{\symbol{"1206A}}
\newcommand\DAGv{\symbol{"1206B}}
\newcommand\DAGw{\symbol{"1206C}}
\newcommand\DAGx{\symbol{"1206D}}
\newcommand\DAM{\symbol{"1206E}}
\newcommand\DAR{\symbol{"1206F}}
%\newcommand\DARA3{\symbol{"12070}}
%\newcommand\DARA4{\symbol{"12071}}
\newcommand\DI{\symbol{"12072}}
\newcommand\DIB{\symbol{"12073}}
\newcommand\DIM{\symbol{"12074}}
\newcommand\DIMb{\symbol{"12075}}
%\newcommand\DIM2{\symbol{"12076}}
\newcommand\DIN{\symbol{"12077}}
\newcommand\DINb{\symbol{"12078}}
\newcommand\DISH{\symbol{"12079}}
\newcommand\DU{\symbol{"1207A}}
\newcommand\DUb{\symbol{"1207B}}
\newcommand\DUc{\symbol{"1207C}}
\newcommand\DUd{\symbol{"1207D}}
\newcommand\DUB{\symbol{"1207E}}
\newcommand\DUBb{\symbol{"1207F}}
%\newcommand\DUB2{\symbol{"12080}}
\newcommand\DUG{\symbol{"12081}}
\newcommand\DUGUD{\symbol{"12082}}
\newcommand\DUH{\symbol{"12083}}
\newcommand\DUN{\symbol{"12084}}
%\newcommand\DUN3{\symbol{"12085}}
%\newcommand\DUN3b{\symbol{"12086}}
%\newcommand\DUN3c{\symbol{"12087}}
%\newcommand\DUN4{\symbol{"12088}}
%\newcommand\DUR2{\symbol{"12089}}
\newcommand\E{\symbol{"1208A}}
\newcommand\Eb{\symbol{"1208B}}
\newcommand\Ec{\symbol{"1208C}}
%\newcommand\E2{\symbol{"1208D}}
%\newcommand\E2b{\symbol{"1208E}}
%\newcommand\E2c{\symbol{"1208F}}
%\newcommand\E2d{\symbol{"12090}}
%\newcommand\E2e{\symbol{"12091}}
%\newcommand\E2f{\symbol{"12092}}
%\newcommand\E2g{\symbol{"12093}}
\newcommand\EDIN{\symbol{"12094}}
\newcommand\EGIR{\symbol{"12095}}
\newcommand\EL{\symbol{"12096}}
\newcommand\EN{\symbol{"12097}}
\newcommand\ENb{\symbol{"12098}}
\newcommand\ENc{\symbol{"12099}}
\newcommand\ENd{\symbol{"1209A}}
\newcommand\ENe{\symbol{"1209B}}
\newcommand\ENf{\symbol{"1209C}}
\newcommand\ENg{\symbol{"1209D}}
\newcommand\EREN{\symbol{"1209E}}
%\newcommand\ERIN2{\symbol{"1209F}}
%\newcommand\ESH2{\symbol{"120A0}}
\newcommand\EZEN{\symbol{"120A1}}
\newcommand\EZENb{\symbol{"120A2}}
\newcommand\EZENc{\symbol{"120A3}}
\newcommand\EZENd{\symbol{"120A4}}
\newcommand\EZENe{\symbol{"120A5}}
\newcommand\EZENf{\symbol{"120A6}}
\newcommand\EZENg{\symbol{"120A7}}
\newcommand\EZENh{\symbol{"120A8}}
\newcommand\EZENi{\symbol{"120A9}}
\newcommand\EZENj{\symbol{"120AA}}
\newcommand\EZENk{\symbol{"120AB}}
\newcommand\EZENl{\symbol{"120AC}}
\newcommand\EZENm{\symbol{"120AD}}
\newcommand\EZENn{\symbol{"120AE}}
\newcommand\EZENo{\symbol{"120AF}}
\newcommand\EZENp{\symbol{"120B0}}
\newcommand\EZENq{\symbol{"120B1}}
\newcommand\EZENr{\symbol{"120B2}}
\newcommand\EZENs{\symbol{"120B3}}
\newcommand\EZENt{\symbol{"120B4}}
\newcommand\GA{\symbol{"120B5}}
\newcommand\GAb{\symbol{"120B6}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120B7}}
%\newcommand\GA2b{\symbol{"120B8}}
%\newcommand\GA2c{\symbol{"120B9}}
%\newcommand\GA2d{\symbol{"120BA}}
%\newcommand\GA2e{\symbol{"120BB}}
%\newcommand\GA2f{\symbol{"120BC}}
%\newcommand\GA2g{\symbol{"120BD}}
%\newcommand\GA2h{\symbol{"120BE}}
%\newcommand\GA2i{\symbol{"120BF}}
%\newcommand\GA2j{\symbol{"120C0}}
%\newcommand\GA2k{\symbol{"120C1}}
%\newcommand\GA2l{\symbol{"120C2}}
%\newcommand\GA2m{\symbol{"120C3}}
%\newcommand\GA2n{\symbol{"120C4}}
%\newcommand\GA2o{\symbol{"120C5}}
%\newcommand\GA2p{\symbol{"120C6}}
%\newcommand\GA2q{\symbol{"120C7}}
%\newcommand\GA2r{\symbol{"120C8}}
%\newcommand\GA2s{\symbol{"120C9}}
%\newcommand\GA2t{\symbol{"120CA}}
%\newcommand\GA2u{\symbol{"120CB}}
%\newcommand\GA2v{\symbol{"120CC}}
%\newcommand\GA2w{\symbol{"120CD}}
%\newcommand\GA2x{\symbol{"120CE}}
%\newcommand\GA2y{\symbol{"120CF}}
%\newcommand\GA2z{\symbol{"120D0}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120D1}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120D2}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120D3}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120D4}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120D5}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120D6}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120D7}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120D8}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120D9}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120DA}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120DB}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120DC}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120DD}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120DE}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120DF}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120E0}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120E1}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120E2}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120E3}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120E4}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120E5}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120E6}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120E7}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120E8}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120E9}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120EA}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120EB}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120EC}}
%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"120ED}}
\newcommand\GABA{\symbol{"120EE}}
\newcommand\GABAb{\symbol{"120EF}}
\newcommand\GAD{\symbol{"120F0}}
\newcommand\GADb{\symbol{"120F1}}
\newcommand\GAL{\symbol{"120F2}}
\newcommand\GALb{\symbol{"120F3}}
\newcommand\GALAM{\symbol{"120F4}}
\newcommand\GAM{\symbol{"120F5}}
\newcommand\GAN{\symbol{"120F6}}
%\newcommand\GAN2{\symbol{"120F7}}
%\newcommand\GAN2b{\symbol{"120F8}}
%\newcommand\GAN2c{\symbol{"120F9}}
%\newcommand\GAN2d{\symbol{"120FA}}
\newcommand\GAR{\symbol{"120FB}}
%\newcommand\GAR3{\symbol{"120FC}}
\newcommand\GASHAN{\symbol{"120FD}}
\newcommand\GESHTIN{\symbol{"120FE}}
\newcommand\GESHTINb{\symbol{"120FF}}
\newcommand\GI{\symbol{"12100}}
\newcommand\GIb{\symbol{"12101}}
\newcommand\GIc{\symbol{"12102}}
\newcommand\GId{\symbol{"12103}}
%\newcommand\GI4{\symbol{"12104}}
%\newcommand\GI4b{\symbol{"12105}}
%\newcommand\GI4c{\symbol{"12106}}
\newcommand\GIDIM{\symbol{"12107}}
%\newcommand\GIR2{\symbol{"12108}}
%\newcommand\GIR2b{\symbol{"12109}}
%\newcommand\GIR3{\symbol{"1210A}}
%\newcommand\GIR3b{\symbol{"1210B}}
%\newcommand\GIR3c{\symbol{"1210C}}
%\newcommand\GIR3d{\symbol{"1210D}}
%\newcommand\GIR3e{\symbol{"1210E}}
%\newcommand\GIR3f{\symbol{"1210F}}
\newcommand\GISAL{\symbol{"12110}}
\newcommand\GISH{\symbol{"12111}}
\newcommand\GISHb{\symbol{"12112}}
\newcommand\GISHc{\symbol{"12113}}
\newcommand\GISHd{\symbol{"12114}}
\newcommand\GISHe{\symbol{"12115}}
\newcommand\GU{\symbol{"12116}}
\newcommand\GUb{\symbol{"12117}}
%\newcommand\GU2{\symbol{"12118}}
%\newcommand\GU2b{\symbol{"12119}}
%\newcommand\GU2c{\symbol{"1211A}}
%\newcommand\GU2d{\symbol{"1211B}}
%\newcommand\GU2e{\symbol{"1211C}}
%\newcommand\GU2f{\symbol{"1211D}}
\newcommand\GUD{\symbol{"1211E}}
\newcommand\GUDb{\symbol{"1211F}}
\newcommand\GUDc{\symbol{"12120}}
\newcommand\GUDd{\symbol{"12121}}
\newcommand\GUL{\symbol{"12122}}
\newcommand\GUM{\symbol{"12123}}
\newcommand\GUMb{\symbol{"12124}}
\newcommand\GUR{\symbol{"12125}}
%\newcommand\GUR7{\symbol{"12126}}
\newcommand\GURUN{\symbol{"12127}}
\newcommand\GURUSH{\symbol{"12128}}
\newcommand\HA{\symbol{"12129}}
\newcommand\HAb{\symbol{"1212A}}
\newcommand\HAc{\symbol{"1212B}}
\newcommand\HAL{\symbol{"1212C}}
\newcommand\HI{\symbol{"1212D}}
\newcommand\HIb{\symbol{"1212E}}
\newcommand\HIc{\symbol{"1212F}}
\newcommand\HId{\symbol{"12130}}
\newcommand\HIe{\symbol{"12131}}
\newcommand\HIf{\symbol{"12132}}
\newcommand\HIg{\symbol{"12133}}
\newcommand\HIh{\symbol{"12134}}
\newcommand\HIi{\symbol{"12135}}
\newcommand\HIj{\symbol{"12136}}
\newcommand\HU{\symbol{"12137}}
%\newcommand\HUB2{\symbol{"12138}}
%\newcommand\HUB2b{\symbol{"12139}}
%\newcommand\HUB2c{\symbol{"1213A}}
%\newcommand\HUB2d{\symbol{"1213B}}
%\newcommand\HUB2e{\symbol{"1213C}}
%\newcommand\HUB2f{\symbol{"1213D}}
%\newcommand\HUL2{\symbol{"1213E}}
\newcommand\I{\symbol{"1213F}}
\newcommand\Ib{\symbol{"12140}}
\newcommand\IB{\symbol{"12141}}
\newcommand\IDIM{\symbol{"12142}}
\newcommand\IDIMb{\symbol{"12143}}
\newcommand\IDIMc{\symbol{"12144}}
\newcommand\IG{\symbol{"12145}}
\newcommand\IGI{\symbol{"12146}}
\newcommand\IGIb{\symbol{"12147}}
\newcommand\IGIc{\symbol{"12148}}
\newcommand\IGId{\symbol{"12149}}
\newcommand\IGIe{\symbol{"1214A}}
\newcommand\IL{\symbol{"1214B}}
\newcommand\ILb{\symbol{"1214C}}
%\newcommand\IL2{\symbol{"1214D}}
\newcommand\IM{\symbol{"1214E}}
\newcommand\IMb{\symbol{"1214F}}
\newcommand\IMc{\symbol{"12150}}
\newcommand\IMd{\symbol{"12151}}
\newcommand\IMe{\symbol{"12152}}
\newcommand\IMIN{\symbol{"12153}}
\newcommand\IN{\symbol{"12154}}
\newcommand\IR{\symbol{"12155}}
\newcommand\ISH{\symbol{"12156}}
\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12157}}
\newcommand\KAb{\symbol{"12158}}
\newcommand\KAc{\symbol{"12159}}
\newcommand\KAd{\symbol{"1215A}}
\newcommand\KAe{\symbol{"1215B}}
\newcommand\KAf{\symbol{"1215C}}
\newcommand\KAg{\symbol{"1215D}}
\newcommand\KAh{\symbol{"1215E}}
\newcommand\KAi{\symbol{"1215F}}
\newcommand\KAj{\symbol{"12160}}
\newcommand\KAk{\symbol{"12161}}
\newcommand\KAl{\symbol{"12162}}
\newcommand\KAm{\symbol{"12163}}
\newcommand\KAn{\symbol{"12164}}
\newcommand\KAo{\symbol{"12165}}
\newcommand\KAp{\symbol{"12166}}
\newcommand\KAq{\symbol{"12167}}
\newcommand\KAr{\symbol{"12168}}
\newcommand\KAs{\symbol{"12169}}
\newcommand\KAt{\symbol{"1216A}}
\newcommand\KAu{\symbol{"1216B}}
\newcommand\KAv{\symbol{"1216C}}
\newcommand\KAw{\symbol{"1216D}}
\newcommand\KAx{\symbol{"1216E}}
\newcommand\KAy{\symbol{"1216F}}
\newcommand\KAz{\symbol{"12170}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12171}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12172}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12173}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12174}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12175}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12176}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12177}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12178}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12179}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"1217A}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"1217B}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"1217C}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"1217D}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"1217E}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"1217F}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12180}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12181}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12182}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12183}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12184}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12185}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12186}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12187}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12188}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"12189}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"1218A}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"1218B}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"1218C}}
%\newcommand\KA2{\symbol{"1218D}}
%\newcommand\KA2b{\symbol{"1218E}}
\newcommand\KAB{\symbol{"1218F}}
%\newcommand\KAD2{\symbol{"12190}}
%\newcommand\KAD3{\symbol{"12191}}
%\newcommand\KAD4{\symbol{"12192}}
%\newcommand\KAD5{\symbol{"12193}}
%\newcommand\KAD5b{\symbol{"12194}}
\newcommand\KAK{\symbol{"12195}}
\newcommand\KAKb{\symbol{"12196}}
\newcommand\KAL{\symbol{"12197}}
\newcommand\KALb{\symbol{"12198}}
\newcommand\KALc{\symbol{"12199}}
%\newcommand\KAM2{\symbol{"1219A}}
%\newcommand\KAM4{\symbol{"1219B}}
\newcommand\KASKAL{\symbol{"1219C}}
\newcommand\KASKALb{\symbol{"1219D}}
\newcommand\KASKALc{\symbol{"1219E}}
%\newcommand\KESH2{\symbol{"1219F}}
\newcommand\KI{\symbol{"121A0}}
\newcommand\KIb{\symbol{"121A1}}
\newcommand\KIc{\symbol{"121A2}}
\newcommand\KId{\symbol{"121A3}}
\newcommand\KID{\symbol{"121A4}}
\newcommand\KIN{\symbol{"121A5}}
\newcommand\KISAL{\symbol{"121A6}}
\newcommand\KISH{\symbol{"121A7}}
%\newcommand\KISIM5{\symbol{"121A8}}
%\newcommand\KISIM5b{\symbol{"121A9}}
\newcommand\KU{\symbol{"121AA}}
\newcommand\KUb{\symbol{"121AB}}
%\newcommand\KU3{\symbol{"121AC}}
%\newcommand\KU4{\symbol{"121AD}}
%\newcommand\KU4b{\symbol{"121AE}}
%\newcommand\KU7{\symbol{"121AF}}
\newcommand\KUL{\symbol{"121B0}}
\newcommand\KULb{\symbol{"121B1}}
\newcommand\KUN{\symbol{"121B2}}
\newcommand\KUR{\symbol{"121B3}}
\newcommand\KURb{\symbol{"121B4}}
%\newcommand\KUSHU2{\symbol{"121B5}}
%\newcommand\KWU318{\symbol{"121B6}}
\newcommand\LA{\symbol{"121B7}}
\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121B8}}
\newcommand\LAGABb{\symbol{"121B9}}
\newcommand\LAGABc{\symbol{"121BA}}
\newcommand\LAGABd{\symbol{"121BB}}
\newcommand\LAGABe{\symbol{"121BC}}
\newcommand\LAGABf{\symbol{"121BD}}
\newcommand\LAGABg{\symbol{"121BE}}
\newcommand\LAGABh{\symbol{"121BF}}
\newcommand\LAGABi{\symbol{"121C0}}
\newcommand\LAGABj{\symbol{"121C1}}
\newcommand\LAGABk{\symbol{"121C2}}
\newcommand\LAGABl{\symbol{"121C3}}
\newcommand\LAGABm{\symbol{"121C4}}
\newcommand\LAGABn{\symbol{"121C5}}
\newcommand\LAGABo{\symbol{"121C6}}
\newcommand\LAGABp{\symbol{"121C7}}
\newcommand\LAGABq{\symbol{"121C8}}
\newcommand\LAGABr{\symbol{"121C9}}
\newcommand\LAGABs{\symbol{"121CA}}
\newcommand\LAGABt{\symbol{"121CB}}
\newcommand\LAGABu{\symbol{"121CC}}
\newcommand\LAGABv{\symbol{"121CD}}
\newcommand\LAGABw{\symbol{"121CE}}
\newcommand\LAGABx{\symbol{"121CF}}
\newcommand\LAGABy{\symbol{"121D0}}
\newcommand\LAGABz{\symbol{"121D1}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121D2}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121D3}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121D4}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121D5}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121D6}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121D7}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121D8}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121D9}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121DA}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121DB}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121DC}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121DD}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121DE}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121DF}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121E0}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121E1}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121E2}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121E3}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121E4}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121E5}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121E6}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121E7}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121E8}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121E9}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121EA}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"121EB}}
\newcommand\LAGAR{\symbol{"121EC}}
\newcommand\LAGARb{\symbol{"121ED}}
\newcommand\LAGARc{\symbol{"121EE}}
\newcommand\LAGARd{\symbol{"121EF}}
\newcommand\LAGARe{\symbol{"121F0}}
\newcommand\LAHSHU{\symbol{"121F1}}
\newcommand\LAL{\symbol{"121F2}}
\newcommand\LALb{\symbol{"121F3}}
\newcommand\LAM{\symbol{"121F4}}
\newcommand\LAMb{\symbol{"121F5}}
\newcommand\LAMc{\symbol{"121F6}}
\newcommand\LI{\symbol{"121F7}}
\newcommand\LIL{\symbol{"121F8}}
%\newcommand\LIMMU2{\symbol{"121F9}}
\newcommand\LISH{\symbol{"121FA}}
\newcommand\LU{\symbol{"121FB}}
\newcommand\LUb{\symbol{"121FC}}
%\newcommand\LU2{\symbol{"121FD}}
%\newcommand\LU2b{\symbol{"121FE}}
%\newcommand\LU2c{\symbol{"121FF}}
%\newcommand\LU2d{\symbol{"12200}}
%\newcommand\LU2e{\symbol{"12201}}
%\newcommand\LU2f{\symbol{"12202}}
%\newcommand\LU2g{\symbol{"12203}}
%\newcommand\LU2h{\symbol{"12204}}
%\newcommand\LU2i{\symbol{"12205}}
%\newcommand\LU2j{\symbol{"12206}}
%\newcommand\LU2k{\symbol{"12207}}
%\newcommand\LU2l{\symbol{"12208}}
%\newcommand\LU2m{\symbol{"12209}}
%\newcommand\LU2n{\symbol{"1220A}}
%\newcommand\LU2o{\symbol{"1220B}}
%\newcommand\LU2p{\symbol{"1220C}}
%\newcommand\LU2q{\symbol{"1220D}}
%\newcommand\LU2r{\symbol{"1220E}}
%\newcommand\LU2s{\symbol{"1220F}}
%\newcommand\LU2t{\symbol{"12210}}
%\newcommand\LU2u{\symbol{"12211}}
%\newcommand\LU2v{\symbol{"12212}}
%\newcommand\LU2w{\symbol{"12213}}
%\newcommand\LU2x{\symbol{"12214}}
%\newcommand\LU2y{\symbol{"12215}}
%\newcommand\LU3{\symbol{"12216}}
\newcommand\LUGAL{\symbol{"12217}}
\newcommand\LUGALb{\symbol{"12218}}
\newcommand\LUGALc{\symbol{"12219}}
\newcommand\LUGALd{\symbol{"1221A}}
\newcommand\LUH{\symbol{"1221B}}
\newcommand\LUL{\symbol{"1221C}}
\newcommand\LUM{\symbol{"1221D}}
\newcommand\LUMb{\symbol{"1221E}}
\newcommand\LUMc{\symbol{"1221F}}
\newcommand\MA{\symbol{"12220}}
\newcommand\MAb{\symbol{"12221}}
\newcommand\MAc{\symbol{"12222}}
%\newcommand\MA2{\symbol{"12223}}
\newcommand\MAH{\symbol{"12224}}
\newcommand\MAR{\symbol{"12225}}
\newcommand\MASH{\symbol{"12226}}
%\newcommand\MASH2{\symbol{"12227}}
\newcommand\ME{\symbol{"12228}}
\newcommand\MES{\symbol{"12229}}
\newcommand\MI{\symbol{"1222A}}
\newcommand\MIN{\symbol{"1222B}}
\newcommand\MU{\symbol{"1222C}}
\newcommand\MUb{\symbol{"1222D}}
\newcommand\MUG{\symbol{"1222E}}
\newcommand\MUGb{\symbol{"1222F}}
\newcommand\MUNSUB{\symbol{"12230}}
%\newcommand\MURGU2{\symbol{"12231}}
\newcommand\MUSH{\symbol{"12232}}
\newcommand\MUSHb{\symbol{"12233}}
\newcommand\MUSHc{\symbol{"12234}}
\newcommand\MUSHd{\symbol{"12235}}
\newcommand\MUSHe{\symbol{"12236}}
\newcommand\MUSHf{\symbol{"12237}}
\newcommand\MUSHg{\symbol{"12238}}
%\newcommand\MUSH3{\symbol{"12239}}
%\newcommand\MUSH3b{\symbol{"1223A}}
%\newcommand\MUSH3c{\symbol{"1223B}}
%\newcommand\MUSH3d{\symbol{"1223C}}
%\newcommand\MUSH3e{\symbol{"1223D}}
\newcommand\NA{\symbol{"1223E}}
%\newcommand\NA2{\symbol{"1223F}}
\newcommand\NAGA{\symbol{"12240}}
\newcommand\NAGAb{\symbol{"12241}}
\newcommand\NAGAc{\symbol{"12242}}
\newcommand\NAGAd{\symbol{"12243}}
\newcommand\NAGAR{\symbol{"12244}}
\newcommand\NAM{\symbol{"12245}}
\newcommand\NAMb{\symbol{"12246}}
%\newcommand\NAM2{\symbol{"12247}}
\newcommand\NE{\symbol{"12248}}
\newcommand\NEb{\symbol{"12249}}
\newcommand\NEc{\symbol{"1224A}}
\newcommand\NEd{\symbol{"1224B}}
\newcommand\NI{\symbol{"1224C}}
\newcommand\NIb{\symbol{"1224D}}
%\newcommand\NI2{\symbol{"1224E}}
\newcommand\NIM{\symbol{"1224F}}
\newcommand\NIMb{\symbol{"12250}}
\newcommand\NIMc{\symbol{"12251}}
%\newcommand\NINDA2{\symbol{"12252}}
%\newcommand\NINDA2b{\symbol{"12253}}
%\newcommand\NINDA2c{\symbol{"12254}}
%\newcommand\NINDA2d{\symbol{"12255}}
%\newcommand\NINDA2e{\symbol{"12256}}
%\newcommand\NINDA2f{\symbol{"12257}}
%\newcommand\NINDA2g{\symbol{"12258}}
%\newcommand\NINDA2h{\symbol{"12259}}
%\newcommand\NINDA2i{\symbol{"1225A}}
%\newcommand\NINDA2j{\symbol{"1225B}}
%\newcommand\NINDA2k{\symbol{"1225C}}
%\newcommand\NINDA2l{\symbol{"1225D}}
%\newcommand\NINDA2m{\symbol{"1225E}}
%\newcommand\NINDA2n{\symbol{"1225F}}
\newcommand\NISAG{\symbol{"12260}}
\newcommand\NU{\symbol{"12261}}
%\newcommand\NU11{\symbol{"12262}}
\newcommand\NUN{\symbol{"12263}}
\newcommand\NUNb{\symbol{"12264}}
\newcommand\NUNc{\symbol{"12265}}
\newcommand\NUNd{\symbol{"12266}}
\newcommand\NUNe{\symbol{"12267}}
\newcommand\NUNf{\symbol{"12268}}
\newcommand\NUNg{\symbol{"12269}}
\newcommand\NUNh{\symbol{"1226A}}
\newcommand\NUNi{\symbol{"1226B}}
\newcommand\NUNj{\symbol{"1226C}}
\newcommand\NUNUZ{\symbol{"1226D}}
\newcommand\NUNUZb{\symbol{"1226E}}
\newcommand\NUNUZc{\symbol{"1226F}}
\newcommand\NUNUZd{\symbol{"12270}}
\newcommand\NUNUZe{\symbol{"12271}}
\newcommand\NUNUZf{\symbol{"12272}}
\newcommand\NUNUZg{\symbol{"12273}}
\newcommand\NUNUZh{\symbol{"12274}}
\newcommand\NUNUZi{\symbol{"12275}}
\newcommand\NUNUZj{\symbol{"12276}}
\newcommand\NUNUZk{\symbol{"12277}}
\newcommand\NUNUZl{\symbol{"12278}}
\newcommand\NUNUZm{\symbol{"12279}}
\newcommand\PA{\symbol{"1227A}}
\newcommand\PAD{\symbol{"1227B}}
\newcommand\PAN{\symbol{"1227C}}
\newcommand\PAP{\symbol{"1227D}}
%\newcommand\PESH2{\symbol{"1227E}}
\newcommand\PI{\symbol{"1227F}}
\newcommand\PIb{\symbol{"12280}}
\newcommand\PIc{\symbol{"12281}}
\newcommand\PId{\symbol{"12282}}
\newcommand\PIe{\symbol{"12283}}
\newcommand\PIf{\symbol{"12284}}
\newcommand\PIg{\symbol{"12285}}
\newcommand\PIh{\symbol{"12286}}
\newcommand\PIi{\symbol{"12287}}
\newcommand\PIj{\symbol{"12288}}
\newcommand\PIk{\symbol{"12289}}
\newcommand\PIRIG{\symbol{"1228A}}
\newcommand\PIRIGb{\symbol{"1228B}}
\newcommand\PIRIGc{\symbol{"1228C}}
\newcommand\PIRIGd{\symbol{"1228D}}
\newcommand\PIRIGe{\symbol{"1228E}}
\newcommand\RA{\symbol{"1228F}}
\newcommand\RAB{\symbol{"12290}}
\newcommand\RI{\symbol{"12291}}
\newcommand\RU{\symbol{"12292}}
\newcommand\SA{\symbol{"12293}}


\begin{document}
{
\Huge
\SAG \UM \U \NIM\NUN\AN\KA  
}

\begin{english}

\end{english}

\end{document}
```

Creating the latex commands is straightforward copy-paste: the unicode names copied from the font coverage button in Babelpad (free), giving this structure:

```
U+12000   CUNEIFORM SIGN A
U+12001   CUNEIFORM SIGN A TIMES A
U+12002   CUNEIFORM SIGN A TIMES BAD
U+12003   CUNEIFORM SIGN A TIMES GAN2 TENU
U+12004   CUNEIFORM SIGN A TIMES HA
U+12005   CUNEIFORM SIGN A TIMES IGI
```

then using LibreOffice (also free)'s spreadsheet app's text manipulation functions MID, FIND, CONCATENATE, so that the commands become \A \Ab \Ac \Ad \Ae \Af.

Answer (score 0):

30,000 character limit on an answer.

Here's the rest of the MWE:

```
\newcommand{\SAG}{\symbol{"12294}}
\newcommand\SAGb{\symbol{"12295}}
\newcommand\SAGc{\symbol{"12296}}
\newcommand\SAGd{\symbol{"12297}}
\newcommand\SAGe{\symbol{"12298}}
\newcommand\SAGf{\symbol{"12299}}
\newcommand\SAGg{\symbol{"1229A}}
\newcommand\SAGh{\symbol{"1229B}}
\newcommand\SAGi{\symbol{"1229C}}
\newcommand\SAGj{\symbol{"1229D}}
\newcommand\SAGk{\symbol{"1229E}}
\newcommand\SAGl{\symbol{"1229F}}
\newcommand\SAGm{\symbol{"122A0}}
\newcommand\SAGn{\symbol{"122A1}}
\newcommand\SAGo{\symbol{"122A2}}
\newcommand\SAGp{\symbol{"122A3}}
\newcommand\SAGq{\symbol{"122A4}}
\newcommand\SAGr{\symbol{"122A5}}
\newcommand\SAGs{\symbol{"122A6}}
\newcommand\SAGt{\symbol{"122A7}}
\newcommand\SAGu{\symbol{"122A8}}
\newcommand\SAL{\symbol{"122A9}}
\newcommand\SALb{\symbol{"122AA}}
%\newcommand\SANGA2{\symbol{"122AB}}
\newcommand\SAR{\symbol{"122AC}}
\newcommand\SHA{\symbol{"122AD}}
%\newcommand\SHA3{\symbol{"122AE}}
%\newcommand\SHA3b{\symbol{"122AF}}
%\newcommand\SHA3c{\symbol{"122B0}}
%\newcommand\SHA3d{\symbol{"122B1}}
%\newcommand\SHA3e{\symbol{"122B2}}
%\newcommand\SHA3f{\symbol{"122B3}}
%\newcommand\SHA3g{\symbol{"122B4}}
%\newcommand\SHA3h{\symbol{"122B5}}
%\newcommand\SHA3i{\symbol{"122B6}}
%\newcommand\SHA6{\symbol{"122B7}}
%\newcommand\SHAB6{\symbol{"122B8}}
%\newcommand\SHAR2{\symbol{"122B9}}
\newcommand\SHE{\symbol{"122BA}}
\newcommand\SHEb{\symbol{"122BB}}
\newcommand\SHEc{\symbol{"122BC}}
\newcommand\SHEd{\symbol{"122BD}}
%\newcommand\SHEG9{\symbol{"122BE}}
\newcommand\SHEN{\symbol{"122BF}}
\newcommand\SHESH{\symbol{"122C0}}
%\newcommand\SHESH2{\symbol{"122C1}}
\newcommand\SHESHLAM{\symbol{"122C2}}
\newcommand\SHID{\symbol{"122C3}}
\newcommand\SHIDb{\symbol{"122C4}}
\newcommand\SHIDc{\symbol{"122C5}}
\newcommand\SHIM{\symbol{"122C6}}
\newcommand\SHIMb{\symbol{"122C7}}
\newcommand\SHIMc{\symbol{"122C8}}
\newcommand\SHIMd{\symbol{"122C9}}
\newcommand\SHIMe{\symbol{"122CA}}
\newcommand\SHIMf{\symbol{"122CB}}
\newcommand\SHIMg{\symbol{"122CC}}
\newcommand\SHIMh{\symbol{"122CD}}
\newcommand\SHIMi{\symbol{"122CE}}
\newcommand\SHIMj{\symbol{"122CF}}
\newcommand\SHIMk{\symbol{"122D0}}
\newcommand\SHIMl{\symbol{"122D1}}
\newcommand\SHINIG{\symbol{"122D2}}
\newcommand\SHIR{\symbol{"122D3}}
\newcommand\SHIRb{\symbol{"122D4}}
\newcommand\SHIRc{\symbol{"122D5}}
\newcommand\SHITA{\symbol{"122D6}}
\newcommand\SHU{\symbol{"122D7}}
\newcommand\SHUb{\symbol{"122D8}}
%\newcommand\SHU2{\symbol{"122D9}}
\newcommand\SHUBUR{\symbol{"122DA}}
\newcommand\SI{\symbol{"122DB}}
\newcommand\SIb{\symbol{"122DC}}
\newcommand\SIG{\symbol{"122DD}}
%\newcommand\SIG4{\symbol{"122DE}}
%\newcommand\SIG4b{\symbol{"122DF}}
%\newcommand\SIK2{\symbol{"122E0}}
%\newcommand\SILA3{\symbol{"122E1}}
\newcommand\SU{\symbol{"122E2}}
\newcommand\SUb{\symbol{"122E3}}
\newcommand\SUD{\symbol{"122E4}}
%\newcommand\SUD2{\symbol{"122E5}}
\newcommand\SUHUR{\symbol{"122E6}}
\newcommand\SUM{\symbol{"122E7}}
\newcommand\SUMASH{\symbol{"122E8}}
\newcommand\SUR{\symbol{"122E9}}
%\newcommand\SUR9{\symbol{"122EA}}
\newcommand\TA{\symbol{"122EB}}
\newcommand\TAb{\symbol{"122EC}}
\newcommand\TAc{\symbol{"122ED}}
\newcommand\TAd{\symbol{"122EE}}
\newcommand\TAe{\symbol{"122EF}}
\newcommand\TAB{\symbol{"122F0}}
\newcommand\TABb{\symbol{"122F1}}
\newcommand\TABc{\symbol{"122F2}}
\newcommand\TAG{\symbol{"122F3}}
\newcommand\TAGb{\symbol{"122F4}}
\newcommand\TAGc{\symbol{"122F5}}
\newcommand\TAGd{\symbol{"122F6}}
\newcommand\TAGe{\symbol{"122F7}}
\newcommand\TAGf{\symbol{"122F8}}
\newcommand\TAGg{\symbol{"122F9}}
%\newcommand\TAK4{\symbol{"122FA}}
\newcommand\TAR{\symbol{"122FB}}
\newcommand\TE{\symbol{"122FC}}
\newcommand\TEb{\symbol{"122FD}}
\newcommand\TI{\symbol{"122FE}}
\newcommand\TIb{\symbol{"122FF}}



\newcommand\TIL{\symbol{"12300}}
\newcommand\TIR{\symbol{"12301}}
\newcommand\TIRb{\symbol{"12302}}
\newcommand\TIRc{\symbol{"12303}}
\newcommand\TIRd{\symbol{"12304}}
\newcommand\TU{\symbol{"12305}}
%\newcommand\TUG2{\symbol{"12306}}
\newcommand\TUK{\symbol{"12307}}
\newcommand\TUM{\symbol{"12308}}
\newcommand\TUR{\symbol{"12309}}
\newcommand\TURb{\symbol{"1230A}}
\newcommand\U{\symbol{"1230B}}
\newcommand\Ub{\symbol{"1230C}}
\newcommand\Uc{\symbol{"1230D}}
\newcommand\Ud{\symbol{"1230E}}
\newcommand\Ue{\symbol{"1230F}}
\newcommand\Uf{\symbol{"12310}}
%\newcommand\U2{\symbol{"12311}}
\newcommand\UB{\symbol{"12312}}
\newcommand\UD{\symbol{"12313}}
\newcommand\UDb{\symbol{"12314}}
\newcommand\UDc{\symbol{"12315}}
\newcommand\UDd{\symbol{"12316}}
\newcommand\UDe{\symbol{"12317}}
\newcommand\UDf{\symbol{"12318}}
\newcommand\UDg{\symbol{"12319}}
\newcommand\UDh{\symbol{"1231A}}
\newcommand\UDi{\symbol{"1231B}}
\newcommand\UDUG{\symbol{"1231C}}
\newcommand\UM{\symbol{"1231D}}
\newcommand\UMb{\symbol{"1231E}}
\newcommand\UMc{\symbol{"1231F}}
\newcommand\UMd{\symbol{"12320}}
\newcommand\UMe{\symbol{"12321}}
\newcommand\UMBIN{\symbol{"12322}}
\newcommand\UMUM{\symbol{"12323}}
\newcommand\UMUMb{\symbol{"12324}}
\newcommand\UMUMc{\symbol{"12325}}
\newcommand\UN{\symbol{"12326}}
\newcommand\UNb{\symbol{"12327}}
\newcommand\UR{\symbol{"12328}}
\newcommand\URb{\symbol{"12329}}
\newcommand\URc{\symbol{"1232A}}
%\newcommand\UR2{\symbol{"1232B}}
%\newcommand\UR2b{\symbol{"1232C}}
%\newcommand\UR2c{\symbol{"1232D}}
%\newcommand\UR2d{\symbol{"1232E}}
%\newcommand\UR2e{\symbol{"1232F}}
%\newcommand\UR2f{\symbol{"12330}}
%\newcommand\UR2g{\symbol{"12331}}
%\newcommand\UR2h{\symbol{"12332}}
%\newcommand\UR2i{\symbol{"12333}}
%\newcommand\UR4{\symbol{"12334}}
\newcommand\URI{\symbol{"12335}}
%\newcommand\URI3{\symbol{"12336}}
\newcommand\URU{\symbol{"12337}}
\newcommand\URUb{\symbol{"12338}}
\newcommand\URUc{\symbol{"12339}}
\newcommand\URUd{\symbol{"1233A}}
\newcommand\URUe{\symbol{"1233B}}
\newcommand\URUf{\symbol{"1233C}}
\newcommand\URUg{\symbol{"1233D}}
\newcommand\URUh{\symbol{"1233E}}
\newcommand\URUi{\symbol{"1233F}}
\newcommand\URUj{\symbol{"12340}}
\newcommand\URUk{\symbol{"12341}}
\newcommand\URUl{\symbol{"12342}}
\newcommand\URUm{\symbol{"12343}}
\newcommand\URUn{\symbol{"12344}}
\newcommand\URUo{\symbol{"12345}}
\newcommand\URUp{\symbol{"12346}}
\newcommand\URUq{\symbol{"12347}}
\newcommand\URUr{\symbol{"12348}}
\newcommand\URUs{\symbol{"12349}}
\newcommand\URUt{\symbol{"1234A}}
\newcommand\URUu{\symbol{"1234B}}
\newcommand\URUv{\symbol{"1234C}}
\newcommand\URUw{\symbol{"1234D}}
\newcommand\URUx{\symbol{"1234E}}
\newcommand\URUDA{\symbol{"1234F}}
\newcommand\URUDAb{\symbol{"12350}}
\newcommand\USH{\symbol{"12351}}
\newcommand\USHb{\symbol{"12352}}
\newcommand\USHc{\symbol{"12353}}
\newcommand\USHd{\symbol{"12354}}
\newcommand\USHe{\symbol{"12355}}
\newcommand\USHX{\symbol{"12356}}
%\newcommand\USH2{\symbol{"12357}}
\newcommand\USHUMX{\symbol{"12358}}
\newcommand\UTUKI{\symbol{"12359}}
%\newcommand\UZ3{\symbol{"1235A}}
%\newcommand\UZ3b{\symbol{"1235B}}
\newcommand\UZU{\symbol{"1235C}}
\newcommand\ZA{\symbol{"1235D}}
\newcommand\ZAb{\symbol{"1235E}}
\newcommand\ZAc{\symbol{"1235F}}
\newcommand\ZAG{\symbol{"12360}}
\newcommand\ZAMX{\symbol{"12361}}
%\newcommand\ZE2{\symbol{"12362}}
\newcommand\ZI{\symbol{"12363}}
\newcommand\ZIb{\symbol{"12364}}
%\newcommand\ZI3{\symbol{"12365}}
\newcommand\ZIB{\symbol{"12366}}
\newcommand\ZIBb{\symbol{"12367}}
\newcommand\ZIG{\symbol{"12368}}
%\newcommand\ZIZ2{\symbol{"12369}}
\newcommand\ZU{\symbol{"1236A}}
%\newcommand\ZU5{\symbol{"1236B}}
%\newcommand\ZU5b{\symbol{"1236C}}
\newcommand\ZUBUR{\symbol{"1236D}}
\newcommand\ZUM{\symbol{"1236E}}
\newcommand\KAP{\symbol{"1236F}}
%%\newcommand\AB{\symbol{"12370}}
%%\newcommand\AB2{\symbol{"12371}}
%\newcommand\AMAR{\symbol{"12372}}
%\newcommand\DAG{\symbol{"12373}}
%%\newcommand\DAG3{\symbol{"12374}}
%\newcommand\DISH{\symbol{"12375}}
%\newcommand\DUB{\symbol{"12376}}
%\newcommand\EZEN{\symbol{"12377}}
%\newcommand\EZENb{\symbol{"12378}}
%%\newcommand\GA2{\symbol{"12379}}
%%\newcommand\GA2b{\symbol{"1237A}}
%%\newcommand\GE22{\symbol{"1237B}}
%\newcommand\GIG{\symbol{"1237C}}
%\newcommand\HUSH{\symbol{"1237D}}
%\newcommand\KA{\symbol{"1237E}}
%\newcommand\KAb{\symbol{"1237F}}
%\newcommand\KAc{\symbol{"12380}}
%\newcommand\KAd{\symbol{"12381}}
%\newcommand\KAe{\symbol{"12382}}
%\newcommand\KAf{\symbol{"12383}}
%\newcommand\KAg{\symbol{"12384}}
%\newcommand\KAh{\symbol{"12385}}
%\newcommand\KAi{\symbol{"12386}}
%\newcommand\KAj{\symbol{"12387}}
%\newcommand\LAGAB{\symbol{"12388}}
%\newcommand\LU2{\symbol{"12389}}
%\newcommand\LU2b{\symbol{"1238A}}
%\newcommand\LU2c{\symbol{"1238B}}
%\newcommand\MESH{\symbol{"1238C}}
%%\newcommand\MUSH3{\symbol{"1238D}}
%%\newcommand\NA4{\symbol{"1238E}}
%\newcommand\NIN{\symbol{"1238F}}
%%\newcommand\NIN9{\symbol{"12390}}
%%\newcommand\NINDA2{\symbol{"12391}}
%%\newcommand\NINDA2b{\symbol{"12392}}
%%\newcommand\NU11{\symbol{"12393}}
%%\newcommand\PESH2{\symbol{"12394}}
%%\newcommand\PIR2{\symbol{"12395}}
%\newcommand\SAG{\symbol{"12396}}
%%\newcommand\TI2{\symbol{"12397}}
%\newcommand\UM{\symbol{"12398}}
%\newcommand\U{\symbol{"12399}}
```