# How do I write the ama-gi symbol in latex?

Tags: symbols

How do I write the ama-gi symbol as text in latex?

[image: amagi]

For ``hegemon'' in ancient greek I can use

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\textgreek{ἡγεμονία}
```

I'd like to be able to do something similar for ama-gi

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You find a high resolution image and use it with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: Since you want to input cuneiform *text* (and this is the keyword), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274916/working-with-old-babylonian-cuneiform-in-texstudio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm sure you know, Ama-gi is a Sumerian word written, in your question, in Classical Sumerian Cuneiform. So we just need a suitable Sumerian font. Now, as you probably know, these - they aren't a dime a dozen. I've managed to find a cuneiform font for the purposes of an MWE, although this font is designed for Akkadian rather than Sumerian. The two languages are very similar, from what I can tell, but I know very little about them. As a result, I'm not sure whether the differences between the symbol in my font, and the symbol in the question are meaningful differences caused by my not having a Sumerian font, or whether it's a meaningless design choice, but you can shop around for a font that suits your needs.

Compile with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\SU}{Akkadian}
\newfontfamily{\GR}[Script=Greek]{Linux Libertine O}

\begin{document}

{\SU } {\GR ἡγεμονία}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Next time, please come up with a minimal working example. This site is a webpage when you have tried all you can, but you are stuck. Please don't use it as a please-do-it-for-me website.

Here, "I" wrote the whole svg picture into a PSTricks file (ok, got me, I only used the Inkscape2PSTricks function):

```
%LaTeX with PSTricks extensions
%%Creator: inkscape 0.91
%%Please note this file requires PSTricks extensions
\psset{xunit=.5pt,yunit=.5pt,runit=.5pt}
\begin{pspicture}(744.09448819,1052.36220472)
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(155.098486,574.86782172)
\curveto(154.098486,599.86781172)(154.268626,689.80527172)(153.098486,710.86782172)
\curveto(152.098486,728.86782172)(126.998796,762.86782172)(128.098486,766.00699172)
\curveto(138.998796,766.86782172)(147.998796,766.86782172)(157.998796,766.86782172)
\curveto(167.998796,766.86782172)(176.998796,766.86782172)(187.998796,765.86782172)
\curveto(188.998796,762.86782172)(164.098486,728.86782172)(163.098486,710.86782172)
\curveto(161.928346,689.80527172)(162.098486,599.86781172)(161.098486,574.86782172)
\curveto(160.978666,571.87223172)(158.998796,564.86783172)(157.998796,564.86783172)
\curveto(156.998796,564.86783172)(155.218306,571.87233172)(155.098486,574.86782172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(143.600406,740.77771172)
\curveto(118.600416,739.77771172)(21.520096,739.94785172)(0.457546,738.77771172)
\curveto(-17.542454,737.77771172)(-51.542454,712.67802172)(-54.681654,713.77771172)
\curveto(-55.542454,724.67802172)(-55.542454,733.67802172)(-55.542454,743.67802172)
\curveto(-55.542454,753.67802172)(-55.542454,762.67802172)(-54.542454,773.67802172)
\curveto(-51.542454,774.67802172)(-17.542454,749.77771172)(0.457546,748.77771172)
\curveto(21.520096,747.60757172)(118.600416,747.77771172)(143.600406,746.77771172)
\curveto(146.595996,746.65789172)(153.600396,744.67802172)(153.600396,743.67802172)
\curveto(153.600396,742.67802172)(146.595896,740.89753172)(143.600406,740.77771172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(-83.542464,595.43925172)
\curveto(-84.542464,620.43925172)(-84.302803,653.37670172)(-85.472943,674.43925172)
\curveto(-86.472943,692.43925172)(-111.572633,726.43925172)(-110.472943,729.57842172)
\curveto(-99.572633,730.43925172)(-90.572633,730.43925172)(-80.572633,730.43925172)
\curveto(-70.572633,730.43925172)(-61.572633,730.43925172)(-50.5726328,729.43925172)
\curveto(-49.5726328,726.43925172)(-74.472943,692.43925172)(-75.472943,674.43925172)
\curveto(-76.643083,653.37670172)(-76.542464,620.43925172)(-77.542464,595.43925172)
\curveto(-77.662284,592.44365172)(-79.642154,585.43925172)(-80.642154,585.43925172)
\curveto(-81.642154,585.43925172)(-83.422644,592.44375172)(-83.542464,595.43925172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(-36.442774,616.43927172)
\curveto(-37.442774,641.43927172)(-37.372324,633.37670172)(-38.542464,654.43925172)
\curveto(-39.542464,672.43925172)(-64.642154,706.43925172)(-63.542464,709.57842172)
\curveto(-52.642154,710.43925172)(-43.642154,710.43925172)(-33.642154,710.43925172)
\curveto(-23.642154,710.43925172)(-14.642154,710.43925172)(-3.642154,709.43925172)
\curveto(-2.642154,706.43925172)(-27.542464,672.43925172)(-28.542464,654.43925172)
\curveto(-29.712604,633.37670172)(-29.442774,641.43927172)(-30.442774,616.43927172)
\curveto(-30.562594,613.44365172)(-32.542464,606.43925172)(-33.542464,606.43925172)
\curveto(-34.542464,606.43925172)(-36.322954,613.44375172)(-36.442774,616.43927172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(138.934716,607.53894172)
\curveto(113.934726,606.53894172)(-30.622764,606.70908172)(-51.685314,605.53894172)
\curveto(-69.685314,604.53894172)(-103.685314,579.43925172)(-106.824514,580.53894172)
\curveto(-107.685314,591.43925172)(-107.685314,600.43925172)(-107.685314,610.43925172)
\curveto(-107.685314,620.43925172)(-107.685314,629.43925172)(-106.685314,640.43925172)
\curveto(-103.685314,641.43925172)(-69.685314,616.53894172)(-51.685314,615.53894172)
\curveto(-30.622764,614.36880172)(113.934726,614.53894172)(138.934716,613.53894172)
\curveto(141.930306,613.41912172)(148.934706,611.43925172)(148.934706,610.43925172)
\curveto(148.934706,609.43925172)(141.930206,607.65876172)(138.934716,607.53894172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(71.752796,626.08031172)
\curveto(71.120166,640.18290172)(71.227806,690.91703172)(70.487536,702.79850172)
\curveto(69.854916,712.95238172)(53.976122,732.13193172)(54.671822,733.90275172)
\curveto(61.567666,734.38835172)(67.261326,734.38835172)(73.587606,734.38835172)
\curveto(79.913906,734.38835172)(85.607556,734.38835172)(92.566476,733.82424172)
\curveto(93.199106,732.13193172)(77.446446,712.95238172)(76.813826,702.79850172)
\curveto(76.073556,690.91703172)(76.181196,640.18290172)(75.548566,626.08031172)
\curveto(75.472766,624.39046172)(74.220246,620.43925172)(73.587606,620.43925172)
\curveto(72.954986,620.43925172)(71.828596,624.39052172)(71.752796,626.08031172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(120.392146,674.62557172)
\curveto(105.228736,673.99294172)(50.678307,674.10058172)(37.903091,673.36031172)
\curveto(26.98542,672.72769172)(6.363154,656.84890172)(4.459131,657.54460172)
\curveto(3.937003,664.44044172)(3.937003,670.13410172)(3.937003,676.46038172)
\curveto(3.937003,682.78668172)(3.937003,688.48033172)(4.543546,695.43925172)
\curveto(6.363154,696.07188172)(26.98542,680.31922172)(37.903091,679.68660172)
\curveto(50.678307,678.94633172)(105.228736,679.05397172)(120.392146,678.42134172)
\curveto(122.209106,678.34554172)(126.457536,677.09302172)(126.457536,676.46038172)
\curveto(126.457536,675.82776172)(122.209046,674.70137172)(120.392146,674.62557172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(111.742566,642.98896172)
\curveto(100.532706,651.56931172)(61.737296,684.26303172)(52.159726,691.33321172)
\curveto(43.974763,697.37539172)(19.075683,697.53990172)(18.166343,699.21110172)
\curveto(22.226915,704.80576172)(25.886729,709.16736172)(29.953184,714.01357172)
\curveto(34.019651,718.85980172)(37.679459,723.22139172)(42.5847,728.18963172)
\curveto(44.287731,727.58645172)(48.854504,703.19084172)(56.226187,696.17943172)
\curveto(64.852086,687.97509172)(103.785876,655.44628172)(114.182436,645.89669172)
\curveto(115.428216,644.75241172)(117.649916,641.25313172)(117.243256,640.76850172)
\curveto(116.836616,640.28389172)(113.085736,641.96085172)(111.742566,642.98896172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(111.018706,709.71614172)
\curveto(101.318696,699.45976172)(64.766266,664.27621172)(56.738036,655.48616172)
\curveto(49.877111,647.97423172)(47.123087,623.22737172)(45.366358,622.49683172)
\curveto(40.2245,627.11742172)(36.26732,631.21113172)(31.870464,635.75970172)
\curveto(27.473592,640.30828172)(23.516423,644.40200172)(19.085462,649.79749172)
\curveto(19.862547,651.42853172)(44.600883,653.43249172)(52.341163,660.03475172)
\curveto(61.398396,667.76029172)(97.801196,703.09863172)(108.380586,712.44527172)
\curveto(109.648266,713.56524172)(113.359696,715.41084172)(113.799386,714.95597172)
\curveto(114.239056,714.50111172)(112.180976,710.94506172)(111.018706,709.71614172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(751.936586,655.59361172)
\curveto(726.936596,654.59361172)(418.520096,654.15652172)(397.457546,652.98638172)
\curveto(379.457546,651.98638172)(345.457536,626.88669172)(342.318366,627.98638172)
\curveto(341.457536,638.88669172)(341.457536,647.88669172)(341.457536,657.88669172)
\curveto(341.457536,667.88669172)(341.457536,676.88669172)(342.457536,687.88669172)
\curveto(345.457536,688.88669172)(379.457546,663.98638172)(397.457546,662.98638172)
\curveto(418.520096,661.81624172)(726.936596,662.59361172)(751.936586,661.59361172)
\curveto(754.932206,661.47379172)(761.936606,659.49392172)(761.936606,658.49392172)
\curveto(761.936606,657.49392172)(754.932106,655.71343172)(751.936586,655.59361172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(338.457536,575.43924172)
\curveto(337.457536,600.43923172)(337.627676,690.37669172)(336.457536,711.43924172)
\curveto(335.457536,729.43924172)(310.357846,763.43924172)(311.457536,766.57841172)
\curveto(322.357846,767.43924172)(331.357846,767.43924172)(341.357846,767.43924172)
\curveto(351.357846,767.43924172)(360.357846,767.43924172)(371.357846,766.43924172)
\curveto(372.357846,763.43924172)(347.457536,729.43924172)(346.457536,711.43924172)
\curveto(345.287396,690.37669172)(345.457536,600.43923172)(344.457536,575.43924172)
\curveto(344.337716,572.44363172)(342.357846,565.43923172)(341.357846,565.43923172)
\curveto(340.357846,565.43923172)(338.577356,572.44373172)(338.457536,575.43924172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(426.491956,582.42181172)
\curveto(415.057886,604.67630172)(377.341196,686.32326172)(367.410806,704.93475172)
\curveto(358.924316,720.84008172)(321.841536,741.10983172)(321.517146,744.42019172)
\curveto(331.041496,749.79090172)(339.204706,753.58063172)(348.274926,757.79145172)
\curveto(357.345156,762.00226172)(365.508346,765.79200172)(375.906686,769.51688172)
\curveto(378.076946,767.21689172)(369.808586,725.89305172)(376.481026,709.14557172)
\curveto(384.288746,689.54862172)(422.314076,608.04494172)(431.934086,584.94830172)
\curveto(433.086806,582.18076172)(434.240436,574.99392172)(433.333406,574.57289172)
\curveto(432.426386,574.15178172)(427.861986,579.75528172)(426.491956,582.42181172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(349.677856,737.12557172)
\curveto(334.514446,736.49294172)(279.964026,736.60058172)(267.188806,735.86031172)
\curveto(256.271136,735.22769172)(235.648866,719.34890172)(233.744846,720.04460172)
\curveto(233.222716,726.94044172)(233.222716,732.63410172)(233.222716,738.96038172)
\curveto(233.222716,745.28668172)(233.222716,750.98033172)(233.829256,757.93925172)
\curveto(235.648866,758.57188172)(256.271136,742.81922172)(267.188806,742.18660172)
\curveto(279.964026,741.44633172)(334.514446,741.55397172)(349.677856,740.92134172)
\curveto(351.494816,740.84554172)(355.743246,739.59302172)(355.743246,738.96038172)
\curveto(355.743246,738.32776172)(351.494756,737.20137172)(349.677856,737.12557172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(339.499286,713.91128172)
\curveto(324.335876,713.27865172)(279.964026,713.38629172)(267.188806,712.64602172)
\curveto(256.271136,712.01340172)(235.648866,696.13461172)(233.744846,696.83031172)
\curveto(233.222716,703.72615172)(233.222716,709.41981172)(233.222716,715.74609172)
\curveto(233.222716,722.07239172)(233.222716,727.76604172)(233.829256,734.72496172)
\curveto(235.648866,735.35759172)(256.271136,719.60493172)(267.188806,718.97231172)
\curveto(279.964026,718.23204172)(324.335876,718.33968172)(339.499286,717.70705172)
\curveto(341.316246,717.63125172)(345.564676,716.37873172)(345.564676,715.74609172)
\curveto(345.564676,715.11347172)(341.316186,713.98708172)(339.499286,713.91128172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(341.629776,683.95918172)
\curveto(329.560416,683.45826172)(286.140876,683.54349172)(275.972406,682.95735172)
\curveto(267.282456,682.45645172)(250.868106,669.88378172)(249.352596,670.43463172)
\curveto(248.937006,675.89469172)(248.937006,680.40287172)(248.937006,685.41196172)
\curveto(248.937006,690.42106172)(248.937006,694.92924172)(249.419786,700.43925172)
\curveto(250.868106,700.94016172)(267.282456,688.46735172)(275.972406,687.96645172)
\curveto(286.140876,687.38031172)(329.560416,687.46554172)(341.629776,686.96463172)
\curveto(343.075986,686.90463172)(346.457536,685.91288172)(346.457536,685.41196172)
\curveto(346.457536,684.91106172)(343.075936,684.01919172)(341.629776,683.95918172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(352.522636,655.03061172)
\curveto(340.453276,654.52969172)(297.033736,654.61492172)(286.865266,654.02878172)
\curveto(278.175316,653.52788172)(261.760966,640.95521172)(260.245456,641.50606172)
\curveto(259.829866,646.96612172)(259.829866,651.47430172)(259.829866,656.48339172)
\curveto(259.829866,661.49249172)(259.829866,666.00067172)(260.312646,671.51068172)
\curveto(261.760966,672.01159172)(278.175316,659.53878172)(286.865266,659.03788172)
\curveto(297.033736,658.45174172)(340.453276,658.53697172)(352.522636,658.03606172)
\curveto(353.968846,657.97606172)(357.350396,656.98431172)(357.350396,656.48339172)
\curveto(357.350396,655.98249172)(353.968796,655.09062172)(352.522636,655.03061172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(342.165496,631.81633172)
\curveto(330.096136,631.31541172)(297.033736,631.57921172)(286.865266,630.99307172)
\curveto(278.175316,630.49217172)(261.760966,617.91950172)(260.245456,618.47035172)
\curveto(259.829866,623.93041172)(259.829866,628.43859172)(259.829866,633.44768172)
\curveto(259.829866,638.45678172)(259.829866,642.96496172)(260.312646,648.47497172)
\curveto(261.760966,648.97588172)(278.175316,636.50307172)(286.865266,636.00217172)
\curveto(297.033736,635.41603172)(330.096136,635.32269172)(342.165496,634.82178172)
\curveto(343.611706,634.76178172)(346.993256,633.77003172)(346.993256,633.26911172)
\curveto(346.993256,632.76821172)(343.611656,631.87634172)(342.165496,631.81633172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(619.439576,617.99172172)
\curveto(611.764816,629.83998172)(586.211386,673.66903172)(579.566536,683.54644172)
\curveto(573.887866,691.98766172)(550.491926,700.50946172)(550.197026,702.38904172)
\curveto(555.901456,706.29390172)(560.814086,709.17207172)(566.272556,712.37003172)
\curveto(571.731046,715.56800172)(576.643656,718.44617172)(582.933146,721.47719172)
\curveto(584.334456,720.33683172)(580.438026,695.82521172)(585.025016,686.74441172)
\curveto(590.392416,676.11858172)(616.131586,632.39835172)(622.714656,619.91050172)
\curveto(623.503476,618.41413172)(624.420126,614.37177172)(623.874276,614.05198172)
\curveto(623.328436,613.73219172)(620.359176,616.57204172)(619.439576,617.99172172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(659.439576,635.13458172)
\curveto(651.764816,646.98284172)(626.211386,690.81189172)(619.566536,700.68930172)
\curveto(613.887866,709.13052172)(590.491926,717.65232172)(590.197026,719.53190172)
\curveto(595.901456,723.43676172)(600.814086,726.31493172)(606.272556,729.51289172)
\curveto(611.731046,732.71086172)(616.643656,735.58903172)(622.933146,738.62005172)
\curveto(624.334456,737.47969172)(620.438026,712.96807172)(625.025016,703.88727172)
\curveto(630.392416,693.26144172)(656.131586,649.54121172)(662.714656,637.05336172)
\curveto(663.503476,635.55699172)(664.420126,631.51463172)(663.874276,631.19484172)
\curveto(663.328436,630.87505172)(660.359176,633.71490172)(659.439576,635.13458172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(697.296716,646.56315172)
\curveto(689.621956,658.41141172)(664.068526,702.24046172)(657.423676,712.11787172)
\curveto(651.745006,720.55909172)(628.349066,729.08089172)(628.054166,730.96047172)
\curveto(633.758596,734.86533172)(638.671226,737.74350172)(644.129696,740.94146172)
\curveto(649.588186,744.13943172)(654.500796,747.01760172)(660.790286,750.04862172)
\curveto(662.191596,748.90826172)(658.295166,724.39664172)(662.882156,715.31584172)
\curveto(668.249556,704.69001172)(693.988726,660.96978172)(700.571796,648.48193172)
\curveto(701.360616,646.98556172)(702.277266,642.94320172)(701.731416,642.62341172)
\curveto(701.185576,642.30362172)(698.216316,645.14347172)(697.296716,646.56315172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(738.368146,661.92029172)
\curveto(730.693386,673.76855172)(705.139956,717.59760172)(698.495106,727.47501172)
\curveto(692.816436,735.91623172)(669.420496,744.43803172)(669.125596,746.31761172)
\curveto(674.830026,750.22247172)(679.742656,753.10064172)(685.201126,756.29860172)
\curveto(690.659616,759.49657172)(695.572226,762.37474172)(701.861716,765.40576172)
\curveto(703.263026,764.26540172)(699.366596,739.75378172)(703.953586,730.67298172)
\curveto(709.320986,720.04715172)(735.060156,676.32692172)(741.643226,663.83907172)
\curveto(742.432046,662.34270172)(743.348696,658.30034172)(742.802846,657.98055172)
\curveto(742.257006,657.66076172)(739.287746,660.50061172)(738.368146,661.92029172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(631.126136,654.02866172)
\curveto(624.656216,641.48178172)(599.313366,597.53061172)(594.042246,586.85672172)
\curveto(589.537566,577.73474172)(593.764846,553.19663172)(592.280126,552.00693172)
\curveto(586.057286,555.01773172)(581.118836,557.85133172)(575.631676,560.99983172)
\curveto(570.144496,564.14823172)(565.206046,566.98193172)(559.450926,570.93453172)
\curveto(559.744426,572.71713172)(582.952966,581.51294172)(588.555086,590.00518172)
\curveto(595.110356,599.94225172)(620.266456,644.00054172)(627.833816,655.91773172)
\curveto(628.740526,657.34568172)(631.793396,660.14947172)(632.342116,659.83462172)
\curveto(632.890826,659.51978172)(631.901306,655.53200172)(631.126136,654.02866172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(678.132746,657.46098172)
\curveto(671.662826,644.91410172)(646.319976,600.96293172)(641.048856,590.28904172)
\curveto(636.544176,581.16706172)(640.771456,556.62893172)(639.286736,555.43923172)
\curveto(633.063896,558.45003172)(628.125446,561.28363172)(622.638286,564.43213172)
\curveto(617.151106,567.58053172)(612.212656,570.41423172)(606.457536,574.36685172)
\curveto(606.751036,576.14945172)(629.959576,584.94526172)(635.561696,593.43750172)
\curveto(642.116966,603.37457172)(667.273066,647.43286172)(674.840426,659.35005172)
\curveto(675.747136,660.77800172)(678.800006,663.58179172)(679.348726,663.26694172)
\curveto(679.897436,662.95210172)(678.907916,658.96432172)(678.132746,657.46098172)
\closepath
}
}
{
\newrgbcolor{curcolor}{0 0 0}
\pscustom[linestyle=none,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=curcolor]
{
\newpath
\moveto(725.989886,661.38955172)
\curveto(719.519966,648.84267172)(694.177116,604.89150172)(688.905996,594.21761172)
\curveto(684.401316,585.09563172)(688.628596,560.55753172)(687.143876,559.36783172)
\curveto(680.921036,562.37863172)(675.982586,565.21223172)(670.495426,568.36073172)
\curveto(665.008246,571.50913172)(660.069796,574.34280172)(654.314676,578.29542172)
\curveto(654.608176,580.07802172)(677.816716,588.87383172)(683.418836,597.36607172)
\curveto(689.974106,607.30314172)(715.130206,651.36143172)(722.697566,663.27862172)
\curveto(723.604276,664.70657172)(726.657146,667.51036172)(727.205866,667.19551172)
\curveto(727.754576,666.88067172)(726.765056,662.89289172)(725.989886,661.38955172)
\closepath
}
}
\end{pspicture}
```

But honestly, `\includegraphics` is the way to go. You could, of course, write it with tikz. But that takes time and is totally unnecessary. But if you want to do that, you are welcome to. You could create one of those nails, rotate and resize it till you have the picture you want to. As I already said: it takes time and is unnecessary. If you still want to, you should try to learn Tikz. But honestly, Tikz is mostly used to create graphics in science, and not for art work. You might consider using a art program to create the amagi symbol - or just copy it.

And next time, please come with a minimal working example. People here offer their spare time to help. You are welcome to get help here, but please, don't do ask people to do the job for you :-)

Hope my answer helped!

Kind regards!

Comment: Thank you for the comment @Ralph. I have updated my question with an example of what I am trying to do.